# IIFE-initialised JS plugin only runs in page load scope

Tags: javascript, firebase-hosting

I am stuck with getting JS plugin (GA-lite) work after it has been initialized via IIFE. It seems the plugin has its own global object after it has been initialized but it only works inside page loading scope and won't work inside the event handlers. Console won't give any errors either. This application is hosted on Firebase. Interestingly the same application will work fine on another hosting however I doubt this is Firebase-specific issue. Perhaps there is something I don't know about passing/sharing/linking objects between IIFE scope and global scope?

Tried removing *a.async=true;*
from JS plugin script tag also tried wrapping IIFE with *setTimeout()*
(not sure if that makes sense anyway) but those did not have any impact

```
(function(e,t,n,i,s,a,c){e[n]=e[n]||function(){(e[n].q=e[n].q||[]).push(arguments)}
;a=t.createElement(i);c=t.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];a.async=true;a.src=s
;c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c)
})(window, document,"galite","script","scripts/ga-lite.min.js");

galite('create', 'UA-11111111-1', 'auto');
galite('send', 'pageview');

// will register
galite('send', 'event', {eventCategory: 'a', eventAction: 'b', eventLabel: 'c'});

// will not register
function onClick() {
    galite('send', 'event', {eventCategory: 'x', eventAction: 'y', eventLabel: 'z'});
}

// will register
function onLoad() {
    galite('send', 'event', {eventCategory: 'w', eventAction: 'w', eventLabel: 'w'});
}

document.getElementById('p-package').addEventListener('click', onClick);
onLoad();
```

UPDATE:
I managed to get *galite* work on clicks by assigning window['galite'] to a global variable from within IIFE then calling that variable inside an event handler and also lowering kb/s (network tab/throttling).
It feels like a JS timing issue now but I hope someone with JS expertise can advise me further as to why this might be happening.

```
var bridge;
(function(e,t,n,i,s,a,c){e[n]=e[n]||function(){(e[n].q=e[n].q||[]).push(arguments)}
;a=t.createElement(i);c=t.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];a.async=true;a.src=s
;c.parentNode.insertBefore(a,c);
bridge = window['galite'];
})(window, document,"galite","script","scripts/ga-lite.min.js");
```

then

```
function onClick() {
    bridge('send', 'event', {eventCategory: 'x', eventAction: 'y', eventLabel: 'z'});
}
document.getElementById('p-package').addEventListener('click', onClick);
```

UPDATE 2:
Found the following line of code inserted into some random location of my HTML file which was destroying my world for a couple of days. I guess one needs using cmd+v with caution.

```
<script async= src="scripts/ga-lite.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of `scripts/ga-lite.min.js`? What does it do? Is that script documented (if you didn't write it yourself)?

Comment: There's only one important line inside that IIFE: `window["galite"]=window["galite"] || function(){ (window["galite"].q=window["galite"].q || []).push(arguments) };` This is what all your immediate calls to `galite(…)` will call, they just fill an array. I would assume that `ga-lite.min.js` then does handle the values inside that array, *and* replace `window["galite"]` with a new function that will immediately handle calls from then on?

Comment: @Bergi, _ga-lite_ is a lightweight Google Analytics version based on the official GA API. I did not have any issues with this implementation on any of my projects except this one. I have updated my question with new details. And yes, you are right, window["galite"] points to `(function(e,t,n,i,s,a,c){e[n]=e[n]||fun...` inside IIFE scope and to some internal `function i(t){if(!Object(o.a)()){for(var e...` when logged to console from within event handler. Any further thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Broke app by accidentally pasting the following line in some random location of my HTML file:

```
<script async= src="scripts/ga-lite.min.js"></script>
```